# Negative Beta and CAPM

Tags: capm

In the case of a stock with negative beta and non-zero volatility, under CAPM the required return is less than the risk-free rate.  This seems contradictory under CAPM assumptions that investors are rational/risk-averse and can invest unlimited amounts at the risk-free rate.

How should required returns less than the risk-free rate be interpreted?  Why would a risk-averse investor purchase a stock with less return than the risk-free rate?

Answer (score 2):

A negative beta investment whose expected return is less than the risk-free rate represents insurance against some macroeconomic risk that adversely affects the rest of the portfolio, therefore, making such a position aligned with the interests of risk-averse investors. Gold is a standard example of a negative beta investment because it acts as a hedge against higher inflation, which ruins financial investments such as stocks and bonds. Put options on stocks and selling forward contracts against indices may likewise have negative betas.

Comment: You could say the 'hedging demand' for a negative beta asset increases its price and lowers the expected return to below the risk free rate.